# Установка .net framework'а на linux mint 18

Tags: linux, .net, linux-mint, wine

[image: Ошибка]

Не могу установить .Net на Linux Mint 18 (т.к. я тесно связан с ФШ, мне он нужен обязательно). С помощью wine и оригинальной версии с сайта майкрософт не получилось. Файл запускается, но я не могу продолжить установку... С вайнтрикса пробовал установить, та-же проблема, только он почему-то про 4 говорит.

Comment: "winetricks" произносится как "вайнтрикс"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас не 32х-битный префикс, вам нужно создать новый, потому что .Net4.5 не совместим с 64х-битной версией Wine.

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
export WINEARCH=win32
winecfg
```

Затем выставьте в окне настроек Windows 7.
И теперь можете устанавливать .Net 4.5 через Winetricks.

Советую выбирать только одну, самую важную для вас версию. Предыдущие будут установлены автоматически, но не все они могут работать совместно, так что некоторые возможно не установятся. Кроме того, внимательно читайте логи. там могут быть важные советы или инструкции (запускайте Winetricks обязательно через терминал).